# ByteTag recognition is unstable on SUR40 (surface 2.0 sdk)

Tags: c#, xna, touch, multi-touch, pixelsense

We are developing applications on a touch table surface [**SUR40**](http://www.samsunglfd.com/product/feature.do?modelCd=SUR40) with **XNA** and **WPF**, but vendor's provided byte-tags which are printed have not worked well on the surface.

The detail is Tags **are blinking** when moving or rotating around the table top (touch surface). And more, **at some angles Tag recognition gets flickering** even at rest state. I have traversed several forums but not so many clear answers for this issue.

I raise some questions here in case someone who experienced the case may give out good advises:

- What's (are) the most important feature(s) for tag recognition: flatness of tags, tag size, tag material, background scene, ... or else.
- How to serialize the producing of tags.

We have tried in quite many ways (using soft thick double-side tape, hard rubber plate, acrylic pieces) but all can get fuzzy manual solutions, in which we can not differentiate why this piece is good but those are not.

Appreciate your all helps as I know this issue is quite secluded in programming area.

P/S: byte tags are here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11029

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this guide for printing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804885(v=surface.10).aspx

And this thread for troubleshooting http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/surfaceappdevelopment/thread/78a9e60d-9f99-400f-9ba9-273843414314/

Tag tracking is known to have degraded between Surface v1 and Surface v2 but those 2 links have tips that can help you hopefully get some better performance.

As for serializing production, I'm not really sure what you mean.  There are only 255 possible values so it doesn't take more than 4 sheets of paper to print a complete set which you can then cut up and use however you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had read through the 2 given links before, actually we are developing on SDK 2.0, but the tags are not diff from 1.0. Sorry not to clear out the 'tags serialization". I meant if we could find a good way to make tags, we would clone them to stick to dozens of our handheld devices.